# How to implement Context menu for custom view in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I am working on Android ICS contacts porting. I want to add a contextual menu for starred(favorites) TAB, but the ListView in that Fragment is very special. There is a normal ListView, and Every item in ListView has two small customized View. I want to implement that when the user press the small view for a longer time, it will show a contextual menu for me.
How do I do? Please give me a hint! thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Where you create your small view add this,

```
    registerForContextMenu(YourSmallView);
```

and in your activity, you can handle the context menu

```
 @Override  
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
}  

 @Override  
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        if(item.getTitle()=="Action 1"){
              function1(item.getItemId());
        }  
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Action 2"){
             function2(item.getItemId());
         }  
        else {
            return false;
        }  
    return true;  
    }
```

Or you can set a long click listener to your view

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using customized List-Items, you can register a specific callback-routine on your desired view. The place to do that is in your bindView() or getView() method.

```
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
tt.setOnLongClickListener(myLongOnClickListener);
```

Comment: It would be a good solution! But I don't know how to implement the contextual menu in this situation. Should I implement all Contextual menu mechanism in this callback function?

Comment: I would try the following:
`ListView lv;`
`lv.showContextMenuForChild(tt);`
or
`lv.showContextMenu();`
Then you should be able to use the standard ContextMenuInflater (see [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) ).